# Algorithm2e does not respect text width when used with exam class

Tags: margins, exam, algorithm2e

As you can see on the picture, the `algorithm` environment (from package `algorithm2e`) does not respect the text width when it is used inside `exam` questions. Actually, it exceeds the right margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\header{Lorem}{Ipsum}{Lorem Ipsum}
\footer{\textsc{Ipsum Lorem}}{}{Page \thepage\slash \pageref*{LastPage}}
\headrule
\footrule
\begin{document}
\section*{Exercise 1}
\begin{questions}
\question \lipsum[1] \newline
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
$n \longleftarrow 0$\;
$u \longleftarrow 280$\;
\While{$u\geq 205$}{
$n \longleftarrow n+1$\;
$u \longleftarrow 0,8u+40$\;
}
\Return n
\end{algorithm}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't need your algorithm to float, you could use `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
...
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.